# Why are the 44-pin connector in laptop IDE (PATA) drives male while the connector in industrial SSD are 44-pin female?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata, pata

I'm working on an old PC-104 board with a **44-pin male connector** (this is 44 metal pins) and I have a SSD drive with a **44-pin female connector** (this is 44 holes) ([One example on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008LA8U8K)).

Now, I want to connect this SSD drive to my PC, and for this I got a SATA to IDE(44-pin PATA) adapter ([The adapter I got](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QN9STY7)) where I carefully selected the one with **44-pin male connector** to found that the SATA side was wrong.

The thing is that 44-pin IDE hard drives have **male** connectors and 44-pin IDE solid state drives have **female** connectors.

So, I have to buy a [IDE to SATA adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085DJD9SQ) and a [gender changer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08SJZZ1CY) in order to connect the SSD to the adapter.

But, still have some doubts. I haven't found information on why the HDD have **male** connectors and SSD have **female** connectors.

Am I missing something? Are the SSD Ide drives another standard? Is the gender changer enough?

Comment: There is no reason other than they thought it was a good idea.

Comment: The hard disks expect to connect with a ribbon cable to the motherboard.  The SSD you show expects to be mounted directly.  I imagine the pinout is such that you just need a 44-pin header to connect a ribbon cable to the SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These SSDs go directly in the mainboard’s IDE port. That’s why they have female connectors. Are there mainboards with a 44-pin IDE port (so with power)? Who knows.

These things also exist for SATA connectors. They are typically called *Disk on Module*.

Comment: You're right. The disk I'm using is a Disk On Module. And, yes, there is embedded mainboards with 44-pin IDE ports. Probably nowadays modern embedded mainboards come with SATA DOM.

Answer (score 0):

For fun reading you could look at the Wikipedia article
[Gender of connectors and fasteners](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_of_connectors_and_fasteners).

In effect, the general idea is that the transmitter is called male
while the receiver is called female, for reasons that I won't get into.
Going in this direction requires getting into the mindset of the
developers of the standard, so where they considered is located the
main transmitter - computer or disk.

It might also have to do with the fact that female connectors are
usually thought to be more durable than male connectors, because it is
so much easier to damage the pins than the female contacts.
So it might have made sense for one set of developers to put the more
fragile male connector on the cable.

Comment: It may be fun reading but it doesn't answer the question ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: Why do you think so, and do you think there is a better answer? I actually think my last paragraph is a good reason for a team to use female connectors.

Comment: As stated many times before in cases of you posting answers like this, this kind of “answer” is simply _not_ an answer. It can simply be a comment. Why you insist posting stuff like this as an answer is beyond me.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I like your thinking on connector and cables. It have me thinking and I'd like to add that a device cable with exposed pins as an male connector is an accident waiting to happen.